# Parse out specific number in filepath

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I pasted several filepaths from a folder into one column in Excel.  I want to parse out a varying eleven-digit number found in every filepath. What is the easiest way to do this?

Here are some sample paths:

```
P:\mppub\Street Name and House Numbering\ADDRESSING_PDF_ARCHIVE\150th_St_E_47083_3314010044_201209.pdf

P:\mppub\Street Name and House Numbering\ADDRESSING_PDF_ARCHIVE\E_Ave_R-4_38320_3362012054_201212.pdf
```

The eleven-digit number would be 3314010044 in the first sample and 3362012054 in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all files follow the same pattern of your 10-digit (you said 11 but from the examples you gave, the paths only have 10 digits) followed by an underscore, 6-digit, a dot then a 3 letter extension, you can try the following formula in G5 if the path is in F5:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(F5,21),10)
```

- `RIGHT(F5,21)` removes the last 21 characters from the path in cell F5
- `LEFT(RIGHT(F5,21),10)` removes the first 10 characters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**IF** the defining characteristic is that your number is the penultimate underscore separated substring, then you can try:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",99)),198),99))
```